# Angular pristine, dirty or touched

Tags: angularjs

I want to check if a model is changed from value without using a form. Is there a method to check that? using model.$pristine or like that isnt giving any results

Answer (score 2):

Use `angular.copy()` to make a deep copy of the original value, then `angular.equals()` to test whether it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.watch('name',function(newValue,oldValue){
// your logic on change
})`. It's not recommended since it reduces the performance, but can be useful at times to look for changes.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-change="functionname"`

and in the script define a function :

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var count=0;
  $scope.functionname=function(){count++;}
});
```

if count is greater than 0 then the input is not pristine.